# Magento 2 send additional mail when creating invoice

Tags: magento2

This is a question about sending the shipment mail after a specific event.

When the shop admin go to "Sales" > "Orders" > "View" (on a pending order) and click "Invoice" there is a possibility to check "Create shipment".

Then when the shop admin click "Invoice" shipment and invoice is completed at the same time.

My problem is that only the invoice email is send and not the shipment mail.

If I do both steps separately both mails are send.

My thinking is that I somehow could listen to the above "event" and trigger sending the shipment mail. Do you have any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: We assume you don't see any admin error, such as "We can't send the shipment right now."? Which Magento2 version you use?

Comment: If the admin checks 'Create Shipment" checkbox, both the invoice and shipment email will be sent to customer.